# Context.lookup(jndiName) is blocking

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, websphere, jndi, ejb-3.0

I have an EJB with the following annotations:

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "jndiName", name = "jndiName")
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
```

I want to send a message to this EJB:

```
Context myContext = getInitialContext(url,login,password);
Object service = myContext.lookup(jndiName);
```

The `jndiName` value is correct, no exception is throwed but the `lookup` function is **blocking**.
In what case the function lookup blocks? What can I do?

P.S. I'm using **WebSphere** as a server.

**EDIT**:
If I use a wrong **jndiName** or a wrong **IP**, an exeption is throwed. In my case there is no exception and no result.

Comment: Uhm...what do you mean with "is blocking" ? Does it ends with a timeout, or are you aware some blocking threads ? I can only think of some network problem, or a lookup on a wrong port. Did you specify all the JNDI parameter correctly ? Especially `Context.PROVIDER_URL`. Why are you using JNDI, is the EJB remote or located in a different ear ?

Comment: yes I put the url.
blocking: lookup function does never end.

Comment: Probably you have already done a quick port scan to see if the url and port are accessible by your remote client.

Comment: Assuming the lookup is blocking it would suggest it found the object, as opposed to thinking it doesn't exist, but something went wrong getting an instance. Getting a javacore would show what is going on to confirm the block.

Comment: Dont know what your `getInitialContext()` method does, but in WebSphere you should call `InitialContext myContext = new InitailContext();` without any other mumbo-jumbo.

Comment: It's already done in getInitialContext